# Android AppCompatSpinner will not dismiss and onItemSelectedListener not called

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a custom adapter for a AppCompatSpinner. the custom adapter is below:

```
class MyAdapter(context: Context, var itemViewRes: Int, var dataSource: List<Product>) : ArrayAdapter<Product>(context, itemViewRes, dataSource) {

override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent)
}


private fun getCustomView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    lateinit var row: View

    parent?.let {
        convertView?.let {
            row = convertView
        } ?: run {
            with(Extensions) {
                row = parent.inflate(itemViewRes)
            }
        }
    }

    with(row) {
        tv_title.text = dataSource[position].displayColor
        var colorHex = dataSource[position].displayColor

        if ("#ffffff".equals(colorHex, ignoreCase = false)) {
            colorHex = "#ededed" //use off-white color as its easier to see
        }

        val backgroundGradient = ib_color.background as? GradientDrawable
        backgroundGradient?.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorHex))

        if (dataSource[position].selectedPosition) {
            (ib_color_container.background as? GradientDrawable)?.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
        } else
            (ib_color_container.background as? GradientDrawable)?.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorHex))

    }
    return row
}
```

}

and here is the item dropdown view xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ib_color_container"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_start"
    android:background="@drawable/round_btn">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_color"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/round_btn" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Regular-Extd.otf"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="pink"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ib_color_container"
    />
```

here is how the spinner is defined in the fragments layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_color"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

and finally here is the spinner setup called from a fragment class:

```
private fun initColorsDropDown(productModel: ProductModel) {
    var productColors = getAllColorProducts(productModel)

    adapterColors = MyAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.product_details_color_item_row, productColors)
    adapterColors?.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.product_details_color_item_row)
    spinner_color.adapter = adapterColors
    spinner_color.onItemSelectedListener = this
}
```

when I run the program in android api 27, i am able to load the spinner with data. the issue is when i click an item the listener does not get fired . but even more strange, the spinner does not dismiss. it stays there no matter where i click. but if i click outside the spinner dropdown it does close.  What am i doing wrong ? i also tried extending SpinnerAdapter instead of arrayAdapter and not using constraintLayout but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

12 hours later i finally figured this out.  your row items all have to set `android:focusable="false"`.  my row items now look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ib_color_container"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_start"
    android:background="@drawable/round_btn">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ib_color"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/round_btn" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Regular-Extd.otf"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="pink"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ib_color_container"
    />
```